# How to use PDFBox to remove Bates Numbering from a PDF?

Tags: java, pdfbox

I am using Apache PDFBox to programmatically remove headers and footers from a PDF. While PDFBox works quite well to remove the basic headers and footers in the PDF, I still cannot remove the "bates number" at the right bottom of each page. Even if I move the bates number right on top of the footer, it's still there after PDFBox removes the footer. There appears to be some kind of z-order going on that I don't understand, or something else.

Using a third-party program like LibreOffice, PDFPenPro, etc., doesn't seem to be instructive to figure out how to remove these bates numbers.

Doing a few searches, I found a site that says that PDFBox doesn't support removing Bates Numbers from a PDF, but I find this difficult to believe.

Here is the sample code I'm using:

```
PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(file);
PDImageXObject pdImage = PDImageXObject.createFromFile("/Users.../white.png", document);
for (PDPage page : document.getPages())
{
    PDRectangle mediaBox = page.getMediaBox();
    float height = mediaBox.getHeight();
    float width = mediaBox.getWidth();
    PDPageContentStream contentStream =
            new PDPageContentStream(document, page,
                    PDPageContentStream.AppendMode.APPEND,
                    true,
                    true);
    contentStream.drawImage(pdImage, 0, 0, width, 50); // cover the header
    contentStream.drawImage(pdImage, 0, height - 50, width, 50); // cover the footer

    // Cover the bates stamp in the right bottom area
    float stampHeight = 15; // The height of the stamp is assumed to be 15 but you should adjust this value as per your needs
    float stampWidth = 50; // The width of the stamp is assumed to be 50 but you should adjust this value as per your needs
    // can't get this to work to cover up the number at lower right...
    // the bates number is an object that I can't overwrite.
    contentStream.drawImage(pdImage, width - stampWidth, 0, stampWidth, stampHeight);
    
    contentStream.close();
    .
    .
    
}
```

Does anyone have experience with PDFBox and removing bates numbers?

Would really appreciate help.

Thanks,

Comment: Please share a PDF with this. There is no concept in PDF about "headers" and "footers". Also show what code you used in your attempts.

Comment: Also, how so you "remove headers and filters"? As you talk about some "z-order" here, it sounds like you actually merely cover them, not remove them.

Comment: Right, a lot of the sample code does just that. It covers the header and footer area with a "white.png" (file name unimportant, of course).

Comment: @KJ *"I suspect observed "Z order" is down to annotation..."* - yes, my suspicion, too. Unfortunately the op did not show their pivotal code, so we did not know whether they handled annotations. Considering their comment here, I assume they don't.

Comment: @Morkus *"Right, a lot of the sample code does just that. It covers the header and footer area with a "white.png""* - (1)  you are aware that covering does not remove the covered data. If you forward the PDF to someone, they can easily "uncover" the covered data. (2) annotations are shown above the static page content. Thus, you also have to handle them, either by actually removing the annotations located in that area or by doing the covering by means of annotations instead of static content.

Comment: I added the sample code above. Note that even when I put the Bates number on top of the footer, it still is not removed (though the footer is). Thanks for suggestions.

Comment: Understood. I believe the client will just do this removal manually due to the complications involved. Thank you.

Comment: @Morkus *"I believe the client will just do this removal manually due to the complications involved."* - Depending on how the Bates numbers are added, it is not difficult to remove them, we merely need to know, _how_ they are applied. If you provided a representative example, we surely could find a simple answer.

Comment: Thanks. I'll check with the client to see if I can share this info.